# Cannot create Test User in iTunes Connect: createPodRedirectResponse() failed

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'd like to create a new Test User for an In-App Purchase service in iTunes Connect, but it always returns:

> createPodRedirectResponse() failed. The likely cause of this is a missing or invalid load-balancer configuration. This request has already been redirected to the same partition instance (40).

I looked up on the internet (and in here), but didn't find out, what was wrong.

I always created new gmail accounts to have a unique id (unique email adress).
When I filled out the form and when I clicked "Save", it gives me the error written above.
When I clicked "Save" again, it sayed, that I should use an other id. So it seems, that Apples iTunes Test User service stores my data. I also get a verify email, but when I verify the account (clicking "Verify now>" in the email and entering my account data in the webpage), it doesn appear in the Test User Account list. When i use the Account, I get an error, saying that the user is not a valid test user.

Is this error temporarely or does it have to do something with my account?

Please help!
Br Nic

Comment: I also have this one randomly during the past days.... :/

Comment: It works again! In the next few days, i'll test the test account service to verify, that it's not a temporarly solution apple has provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been having the same problem for several days. I'm waiting for Apple's guys to fix it. Check Apple's developer forum (in-app purchase section) for details.

Comment: It appears that Apples servce somehow didn't work. So i had to wait.

Comment: How much time it took? I have same issue but didn't found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I just got one to through. I kept pressing "save" and replacing the email address with a new fake email address incremented by 1 in front of the @ sign. (you don't need a real address for test accoutns).

Comment: Hi jimivg! In my point of view there is a need to have a valid email adress. Otherwhise the test user account can't be confirmed.

Comment: Hi jimivg, you're right!! There is no need to have a valid email adress. I tested this with a not validated email adress. But in case, apple somehow deletes unverified accounts, i'd suggest to create a valid email adress.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I had the same issue always in Chrome, but not in Safari. There it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's solution worked for me. It works in Safari, however you will need to "reset" the browser by going to Safari > Reset Safari... EVERYTIME you need to create a new Test User.

Comment: Good answer! But i work with Firefox (should be no ad ;-) ) and after waiting a day, it worked again. But Thank you for your contribution!